# Getting CORS policy preflight request headers error when calling API Endpoint of ASP.net Core Webapi

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors

i'm reading stackoverflow posts now for many years and they always helped me lot solving my problems. Thank you all a lot for that.  Now i couldn't find a helpful answer to my question so that was a good opportunity to register :-)

My Question:
I have a ASP.net Core WebApi to authorize and authenticate users (.net 7). I'm running into a CORS problem when calling the login endpoint of that API using my Angular App:
`Access to fetch at 'https://myAPI.azurewebsites.net/accounts/authenticate' from origin 'https://myAPP.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

When i call the endpoint with Postman everything is fine and i'm getting the response as expected. My Login method in the frontend is simply:

```
  login(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${baseUrl}/authenticate`, { email, password }, { withCredentials: true })
            .pipe(map(account => {
                this.accountSubject.next(account);
                this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
                return account;
            }));
    }
```

The Program.cs looks like following:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// add services to DI container
{
    var services = builder.Services;
    var env = builder.Environment;

    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => 
    {
        // serialize enums as strings in api responses (e.g. Role)
        x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });

    services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    services.AddSwaggerGen();

    // configure strongly typed settings object
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    // configure DI for application services
    services.AddScoped<IJwtUtils, JwtUtils>();
    services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
    services.AddScoped<IMailService, EmailService>();
 builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MailSettings)));
    
}

var app = builder.Build();

// migrate any database changes on startup (includes initial db creation)
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dataContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();    
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(x => x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", ".NET Sign-up and Verification API"));

app.UseCors(x => x
   .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
   .AllowAnyMethod()
   .AllowAnyHeader()
   .AllowCredentials());

// global error handler
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();

// custom jwt auth middleware
app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run(builder.Configuration["AppSettings:origins"]);
```

That results is the CORS policy error message as seen above.
I also tried to set up my own custom CORS Policy:

```
.
.
.
// global cors policy
app.UseCors(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins
                ("http://localhost:8100",
                "https://myAPP.azurewebsites.net",
                "https://API1.azurewebsites.net",
                "https://API2.azurewebsites.net",
                "https://www.myDomain.de")
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .WithMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
        }
    );
.
.
.
```

The results are the same. I played a bit around with the different settings and read a lot here on stackoverflow but i feel a bit stuck, so every help is very much apreciated :-)

See in Description above.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you set the response header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

at the same time,which is not allowed,you could check this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) related

Juding from your codes,the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`  was not setted by Cors middleware ,you need to check if it was setted somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot more reading i found the solution to my problem. The Problem was actually in the configuration of the Azure Web App.
There is an option to set a CORS Configuration which i did a longer time ago. I set the origin to * and didn't check the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Option there.
I simply forgot about the changes i made there.

[Azure Web-App Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXtPQ.png)

Hope this might help someone out there.

Thank you Ruikai Feng. Your answer led me to solution eventually.